# How to make array value with comma separated in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

We have string array in XML look like:

```
<arr name="CategoryName">
   <str>Movies</str>
   <str>Movies</str>
   <str>Movies</str>
   <str>Movies</str>
   <str>Movies</str>
   <str>DVD</str>
   <str>By Languages</str>
   <str>By Title</str>
   <str>By Decades</str>
   <str>By Genre</str>
   <str>2000's</str>
   <str>Drama</str>
   <str>English</str>
   <str>QRST</str>
</arr>
```

and my output from xslt transformation look like:

```
<category>MoviesMoviesMoviesMoviesMoviesDVDBy LanguagesBy TitleBy DecadesBy Genre2000'sDramaEnglishQRST</category>
```

but i want to each element with comma separated like:

```
<category>Movies, Movies, Movies, Movies, Movies, DVD, By Languages, By Title, By Decades, By Genre, 2000's,Drama,English,QRST</category>
```

And my XSLT code look like:

```
<xsl:variable name="CategoryArray" select ="arr[@name = 'CategoryName']"/>

 <xsl:for-each select="$CategoryArray">
        <category><xsl:value-of select="concat($CategoryArray,', ')"/></category>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

but its not working so pls give me solution for how make array value with comma separated.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell what your code is doing without seeing how `$CategoryArray` is defined. However, there are 2 main problems with your code:

1. The `xsl:for-each` needs to go inside the `category` element, because you only want one of these elements for every array
2. Using your code, the list will end with a comma. To do this, you have to process the first item separately.

You can use this XSLT to do this:

```
<category>
  <xsl:if test="arr/str">
    <!-- Process the first item separately -->
    <xsl:value-of select="arr/str[1]"/>
    <!-- Process the rest of the items, skipping the first using position() -->
    <xsl:for-each select="arr/str[position() != 1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(', ',.)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:if>
</category>
```

Comment: I see. Your code will concat all elements and apply a single comma at the very end (not sure why you're not seeing it, it should be there)

Comment: This is XSLT 2.0, so there are much easier solutions.

Comment: @MichaelKay Right, I didn't notice the tag. I just assumed it was 1.1, as the support for 2.0 is so bad (in my experience, at least...)

Comment: Depends where your experience is. It's true there are many environments were 2.0 is not readily available (e.g. PHP). But I'm surprised you mention 1.1: that's completely dead. You're using 1.0 if you're a laggard, 2.0 if you're mainstream, 3.0 if you're bleeding edge.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$CategoryArray">
    <category><xsl:value-of select="concat($CategoryArray,', ')"/></category>
</xsl:for-each>
```

with this:

```
<category><xsl:value-of select="$CategoryArray" separator=", "/></category>
```

Comment: Don't tell us things aren't working, tell us how they fail. Are you sure you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor? (Lots of people seem to think that saying version="2.0" in the stylesheet will magically give them a 2.0 processor).

Comment: I face very similar issue, can you advise How can make sure I'm using xslt 2.0? is there any way to findout that?

Comment: How can be sure i am using xlst 2.0? can you pls tell me how to check version of xslt?

Comment: You can check the version using `system-property('xsl:version')`.